# What is enum assignment inside the class?

Tags: typescript

Inside a Typescript class, why can we do something like `P = p` ? where `p` is enum e.g.

```
enum p {a = 'a', b = 'b'}

class X { P = p; }

// ERROR
P = p;
```

But if write it outside of class, doesn't work. What `P = p` does?

Comment: Is it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields you're not familiar with? The error tells you what the problem is outside the class, `P` isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with an enum and would be true of any value. Let's replace `p` with `1` for simplicity.

```
class X { P = 1; }
```

This declares a class `X` with one (public) instance variable `P`. That instance variable will be initialized, at instance construction time, to the value `1`. Its type is inferred to be `number`, since you didn't specify.

```
P = 1;
```

This says that the variable `P` in the current scope should be given the value `1`. There is no variable `P` in the current scope, so this is an error.

Now, why does this work with an enum? Enums aren't just types in Typescript; they're also values. Specifically, your enum

```
enum p {a = 'a', b = 'b'}
```

will be this dictionary at runtime

```
const p = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}
```

That is, it's a mapping from the names of the enum constants to their values (which happen to be the same in this example but won't always be). If you were using numerical constants rather than strings, you'd also get the reverse mapping.

So when you use `p` in a context expecting a value, you get a value of type `{a: "a", b: "b"}` which encodes the enum constants.